# Average of field from subquery with limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble generating a query that I'm sure is possible. I have a `products` table and a `product_changes` table. I would like to select the average of the `product_changes.rank` field for the top 30 lowest values for each associated product.

Here are the relevant table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE product_changes (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  product_id integer,
  rank integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone
);
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
SELECT products.id, avg_rank 
FROM "products" 
JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, AVG(rank) avg_rank
  FROM product_changes 
  GROUP BY product_id, rank
  ORDER BY rank ASC NULLS LAST
  LIMIT 10) pc ON pc.product_id = products.id
WHERE avg_rank IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 10
```

However, this is giving me the same average of the lowest 30 rank values for each row of the results. That would seem like the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` isn't working, but I'm sure it's just my misunderstanding of something.

Comment: As always, table definitions and Postgres version would help. You mention a  `rank field for each product`, but I don't see that column in your query ...

Comment: Updated question to include table definitions and clarification about rank field.  Sorry it took me so long.  This is a side project and got just got time to get back to it.  Reading through the answers now.

Comment: You might want to clarify the objective as well. `the average of the product_changes.rank field for the top 30 lowest values for each associated product` is ambiguous. I tried to answer *some* possible interpretations. Is one of them what you want? Please clarify.

Comment: FYI, I edited my question for clarity about what I was looking for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some room for interpretation in your question ...

You probably want *the average of the 30 lowest `rank` values in `product_changes` for each product.*

Unless you want to include products without related rows in `product_changes`, you can get fast results by looking at only `product_changes` - using the [window function `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) in a subquery:

```
SELECT id, avg(rank ) AS avg_rank
FROM  (
   SELECT product_id AS id, rank 
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY rank) AS rn
   FROM   product_changes 
   ) sub
WHERE  rn <= 30
GROUP  BY id;
```

Or maybe you meant *30 products with the lowest value in `products.rank` and the average `rank` in related rows in `product_changes`*:

```
SELECT p.id, pc.avg_rank 
FROM  (
   SELECT id
   FROM   products
   ORDER  BY rank
   LIMIT  30
   ) p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT avg(rank) avg_rank
   FROM   product_changes 
   WHERE  product_id = p.id
   ) pc ON true;
```

Why `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`?

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

If there is no column `products.rank`, and you actually meant *30 products with the lowest value in `product_changes.rank`*:

```
SELECT p.id, pc.avg_rank 
FROM  (
   SELECT product_id AS id
   FROM   product_changes
   ORDER  BY rank
   LIMIT  30
   ) p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT avg(rank) avg_rank
   FROM   product_changes 
   WHERE  product_id = p.id
   ) pc ON true;
```

Comment: Your first solution was what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `LATERAL` subquery or a correlated subquery to ensure that the subquery is executed for each product. Here's an example:

```
SELECT products.id, avg_rank 
FROM "products",
     LATERAL (
         SELECT AVG(rank) avg_rank
         FROM (SELECT rank
               FROM product_changes
               WHERE product_id=products.id
               ORDER BY rank ASC NULLS LAST
               LIMIT 30) t1
     ) t2
WHERE avg_rank IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 10
```